# stop recursion for recursive_directory_operator c++

Tags: c++, filesystems, iteration

So let's say i have this code that looks for documents of mine and prints the path to them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>

using namespace std;

string extensions[3] = { ".doc", ".docx", ".txt" }; // things to look for
string ignoredirs[2] = { "Windows", "Program Files",  } // and other ones that i was too 
                                                        // lazy to write in there
using namespace std::experimental::filesystem;

path yee;
void main()
{
    for (recursive_directory_iterator i("c:\\"), end; i != end; ++i)
        if (!is_directory(i->path()) && i->path().has_extension()) // checks if the file
                                                                   // even has an extension
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= 3; ++x)
                if (i->path().extension().string() == extensions[x])// checks if the 
                                                                    // extension is equal  
                                                                    // to current
                                                                    // extension in loop
                    cout << "found document at :" ;
                    cout << i->path().string() << endl; // print out the path
        }

}
```

And I would like to not iterate to directories in `ignoredir[]` because it takes ages to find my docs on the `filesystem`.

I saw this [code](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/recursive_directory_iterator/disable_recursion_pending) from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com).

Could someone explain me the the code and/or how to use it in my use case?

Pr could you submit a better solution than that?

Ps. I don't want to use boost in this program, just to see how it works in `experimental::filesystem`

Comment: Just change `if(i->path().filename() == "b")` to code that checks whether the filename is in `ignoredirs`. Do you know how to check if a string is in an array?

Comment: Instead of an array, I suggest you use `std::set`. Then just check whether the string is in the set.

Comment: `main` is required to have the return type `int` in c++.

Comment: barmar - Thanks, I forgot i can actually do it like this :D

Comment: I know that main should be int, but I don't care. It's not giving me compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

set<string> extensions = { ".doc", ".docx", ".txt" }; //things to look for
set<string> ignoredirs = { "Windows", "Program Files" }; //and other ones that i was too lazy to write in there
using namespace std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
    for (recursive_directory_iterator i("c:\\"), end; i != end; ++i)
    {
        if (!is_directory(i->path()) && i->path().has_extension()) // checks ifthe file even has an extension
        {
            if (extensions.find(i->path().extension().string()) != extensions.end())
                cout << "found document at :";
            cout << i->path().string() << endl; //print out the path

        }

        if (ignoredirs.find(i->path().filename().string()) != ignoredirs.end())
            i.disable_recursion_pending();
    }
}
```

Explanation:

`i->path().filename()` actually return directory name, when the same directory name is in `set<>` then `i.disable_recursion_pending();` is called. When this one is called `recursive_directory_iterator i` omit directory with `i->path().filename()` name.

`set<string>` was used to get rid internal `for` loop that requires size of table, which is error prone. Also performance gain and code simplification

Notice:

On windows directory names should be compared case insensitive. Also Windows 64bit have "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)" and both need to be listed in ignore list (or string comparison need to be improved)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Now i understand it.